# Outlook 2010 C++ add-in - HTML email body retrieval

Tags: c++, email, com, outlook, add-in

I'm writing an outlook 2010 add-in, my add-in appends a footer to emails according to each email format (plain text/HTML), now I just discovered a problem that happens when I enable the outlook "Read emails as plain text" feature (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831607), what happens is my add-in receives HTML emails as plain text, so it adds the footer and saves them accordingly which is a problem because after saving as plain text, the actual HTML version of the email is completely lost from outlook.

Here's my code (edited for brevity):

```
void CConnect::OnNewItem(IDispatch* item)
{
    if (item)
    {
        CComQIPtr<Outlook::_MailItem> mailItem(item);

        OlBodyFormat bodyFormat;
        mailItem->get_BodyFormat(&bodyFormat);

        CComBSTR body;
        if(bodyFormat == olFormatPlain)
            mailItem->get_Body(&body);
        if(bodyFormat == olFormatHTML)
            mailItem->get_HTMLBody(&body);

        //append the footer here

        if(bodyFormat == olFormatPlain)
            mailItem->put_Body(newBody);
        if(bodyFormat == olFormatHTML)
            mailItem->put_HTMLBody(newBody);

        mailItem->Save();
        mailItem->Release();
    }
}
```

I also tried getting the HTML body of emails no matter what their format actually is, but I get a generated HTML version of the plain text version, so all the original CSS and formatting is lost.

What I need is a way to be able to retrieve the original HTML version when the outlook "Read emails as plain text" feature is on, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit dated, but just saw this now...

You are probably going to need to drop down to the MAPI level to do this properly.  Something like:

```
LPMESSAGE MapiMessage;
HRESULT ResultCode  = HrGetOneProp(MapiMessage, PR_HTML, &PropertiesValues);
LPSBinary HtmlBodyProperty = (LPSBinary)&PropertiesValues->Value.bin;
```

Integrating MAPI support into your addin is not as painful as some people might think.  A good starting point is "[Using MAPI to Create Outlook 2007 Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc678348%28v=office.12%29.aspx)".

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: If you feel inclined, perhaps mark this as the answer.  Nice to show other people what helps.